# SvelteKit: next & prev posts in markdown blog

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a blog being developed on SvelteKit using markdown articles. I would like to make sure that in each article I have a block that would point to the previous and next blog posts. Let's start with the fact that I have a utility function that pulls these posts from md files

```js
/*lib/utils/getPosts.js*/

// @ts-nocheck
export const getMarkdownPosts = async () => {
    const allPostFiles =
        import.meta.glob('/src/content/posts/*.md')
    const iterablePostFiles = Object.entries(allPostFiles)

    const allPosts = await Promise.all(
        iterablePostFiles.map(async ([path, resolver]) => {
            const { metadata } = await resolver()
            //const postPath = path.slice(11, -3)

            const postPath = path.split('/').at(-1)?.replace('.md', '')

            return {
                meta: metadata,
                path: postPath,
            }
        })
    )

    return allPosts
}
```

Then I have a server function in `api/posts/+server.js`

```js
/*api/posts/+server.js*/

import { getMarkdownPosts } from '$lib/utils/getPosts'
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit'

export const GET = async () => {
  const allPosts = await getMarkdownPosts()

  const sortedPosts = allPosts.sort((a, b) => {
    return new Date(b.meta.date) - new Date(a.meta.date)
  })

  return json(sortedPosts)
}
```

Here is the load function that serves to build the article page.

```js
/*blog/[slug]/+page.js*/

export async function load({ params }){

    const post = await import(`../../../content/posts/${params.slug}.md`)
    const { title, date, categories, draft } = post.metadata
    const content = post.default

    return {
      content,
      title,
      date,
      categories
    }
}
```

I need to sort through the articles in the array and select 1 previous and 1 next, depending on the article that is currently open. I can do it, for example, like this

```js
/*api/posts/+server.js*/

import { getMarkdownPosts } from '$lib/utils/getPosts'
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit'

export const GET = async () => {
  const allPosts = await getMarkdownPosts()

  //const notDraftPosts = allPosts.filter(post => post.meta.draft === false)

  const sortedPosts = allPosts.sort((a, b) => {
    return new Date(b.meta.date) - new Date(a.meta.date)
  }).map((post, index, allPosts) => ({
    ...post,
    next: allPosts[index - 1] || 0,
    previous: allPosts[index + 1] || 0,
}));


  return json(sortedPosts)
}
```

But I'm not sure it's even right. And I don't know how to use these next and prev later in my article template

```html
/*blog/[slug]/+page.svelte*/
<script>
    export let data
    import { dateFormat } from '$lib/utils/dateFormat.js';

    console.log(data)
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <title>My blog - {data.title}</title>
  <meta property="og:title" content={data.title} />
</svelte:head>

<article>
    <h1>{ data.title }</h1>
    {#if data.categories.length}
    <ul>
        {#each data.categories as category}
          <li>
            <a href="/blog/category/{category}">
              {category}
            </a>
          </li>
        {/each}
      </ul>
    {/if}
    <p>Published: {dateFormat(data.date)}</p>
    <svelte:component this={data.content} />
</article>
```

Can someone tell me?

Answer (score 0):

Your `load` function should also return the next and previous post:

```js
/*blog/[slug]/+page.js*/

export async function load({ params }){
  const post = await import(`../../../content/posts/${params.slug}.md`)
  const { title, date, categories, draft } = post.metadata
  const content = post.default

  return {
    content,
    title,
    date,
    categories,
    // this is new
    next,
    previous
  }
}
```

Now it is just a matter of figuring out the `next` and `previous` post during load, if you move the load to `+page.server.js` instead this will become a lot easier as you can simply call your `getMarkdownPosts` function and search in there.

Not sure why you have all the `+server.js`, these don't look necessary for this case.

extra note:

If you are making a static build (that you have to run again each time you publish a post) you could make `getMarkdownPosts` more efficient by 'caching the result' instead of doing all that work again each time.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did. Shows `undefined` if output to `console.log(next)`